# Black screen after splash for a few seconds on iOS from Unreal Engine

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, unreal-engine4

Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

I have an AR app for iOS with Unreal Engine 4.24
All is ok, but after running on the device, it shows a black screen for a few seconds and then opens the main page.

Comment: It probably takes a bit time for everything to "warm up" before your scene starts. In such cases I usually overlay the screen with same view controller as splash screen. Would that be an acceptable solution for you as well? Anyway, it would still be nice to get some event when scene starts drawing to remove the overlay. Otherwise I guess some timer could be enough which removes the overlay after "a few sec.".